# Unix - Filter Commands

Tags: command-line, pipe

I want to know about the "filter-command" which are available in Unix.
I am confused regarding this:

1. What is the purpose of "Filter-Command" ?
2. Which are the Filter-commands available in Unix?

I have read some books/articles on web, in some books i found few filter commands and in some books i found some other.

Comment: Is this a question from some kind of exam or what is the context?

Comment: @echox no it was not for any exam...but i just wants a list of Filter commands which are being used in shell-script because i was confused about the total Filter commands...in some books i found some and in another i found some other

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking without context. "Traditional" Unix tools read from standard input and write to standard output, so you can chain them together using a pipe, which is the | command:

```
 ls | grep "banana" | more
```

Things which read from standard input and write to standard output are filters.

There is an article here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(Unix)

Comment: ya exactly what i was looking for....i just wants a list of Filter commands which are being used in shell-script becoz i was confused about the total Filter commands...in some books i found some and in another i found some other..but this link provides All filter commands...thanx

Answer (score 3):

A filter command is almost any command line program on UNIX, really.

Every program that can read from `STDIN`and output to `STDOUT` can be used as filter.

There are exceptions, though. One such exception is `cpio`, which takes a list of files from `STDIN` to create an archive on output.

There are some commands, that seem not to be able to read from `STDIN`, though you should check whether those commands use `-` as file parameter to read from `STDIN` or write to `STDOUT`, like `cat`:

> ```
> $ cat f - g
> ```
>
> Output f’s contents, then standard input, then g’s contents.

But even when your program does not use that, you can **still** usually force a program to act as a filter:

For instance take `wget` and you want to make that program output to `STDOUT`:

```
$ wget -O /dev/stdout http://stackoverflow.com/ | less
```

**i.e.:** You can use `/dev/stdin`, `/dev/stdout`, and `/dev/stderr`, as files to force a program to read, or output into the standard-IO descriptors.

Another side note: The length of your pipe, can be as long as you wish, so you can pipe from one program to another, basically making it a long chain of filters:

```
$ cat file | xz | ccrypt &>/dev/null
```

Comment: The last example doesn't make too much sense, I give you that. It's just used as a valid example.

Comment: +1, the last example is kinda like goverments... a lot of effort and boha that goes nowhere...